# Derivation of Monte Carlo Policy Gradient for REINFORCE

Tags: reinforcement-learning

On page 270 of [this draft](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf) of Intro to Reinforcement Learning by Sutton and Burton, the authors simplify the policy gradient as follows:

[image]

Since the action-value function equals the conditional expectation of the cumulative reward, the intermediate step in moving from line 2 to 3 is presumably:

[image]

Why can you just drop the inner expectation to arrive at line 3?

Answer (score 2):

In my proof I use related **random variables** as the subscript of expectations rather than the **policy $\pi$**. It may make the expressions look more complicated but it makes the notion more clear.

---

The proof is based on two facts:

#### Fact 1.

$$
y\mathbb{E}_{X|Y=y}[X|Y=y]=\mathbb{E}_{X|Y=y}[Xy|Y=y]
$$

The left part is actually a function of $y$ so in $\mathbb{E}_{X|Y=y}[\cdot]$'s view **$y$ is  a constant**. Thus it can be put into the expectation **by linearity**. You can also prove it easily as below:
$$
\begin{align}
y\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]&=y\sum_xp_{X|Y=y}(x|y)x\\
&=\sum_xp_{X|Y=y}(x|y)xy\\
&=\mathbb{E}[Xy|Y=y]\\
\end{align}
$$

#### Fact 2.

$$
\mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[g(X,Y)|X]]=\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[g(X,Y)]
$$

It is a generalization of ***the Law of Total Expectation***. You can also easily prove it as below:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[g(X,Y)|X]]&=\sum_xp_X(x)\mathbb{E}_{Y|X=x}[g(x,Y)|X=x]\\
&=\sum_xp_X(x)\sum_yp_{Y|X=x}(y|x)g(x,y)\\
&=\sum_x\sum_yp_X(x)p_{Y|X=x}(y|x)g(x,y)\\
&=\sum_x\sum_yp_{X,Y}(x,y)g(x,y)\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}[g(X,Y)]
\end{align}
$$

#### The final proof.

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla J(\theta)&=\mathbb{E}_{S_t,A_t}\left[q_\pi(S_t,A_t)\nabla\ln\pi_\theta(A_t|S_t)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{S_t,A_t}\Big[\mathbb{E}_{G_t|S_t,A_t}[G_t|S_t,A_t]\nabla\ln\pi_\theta(A_t|S_t)\Big]\tag{Definition of $q$}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{S_t,A_t}\Big[\mathbb{E}_{G_t|S_t,A_t}\big[G_t\nabla\ln\pi_\theta(A_t|S_t)|S_t,A_t\big]\Big]\tag{Fact 1.}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{G_t,S_t,A_t}\big[G_t\nabla\ln\pi_\theta(A_t|S_t)\big]\tag{Fact 2.}
\end{align}
$$

(Note: for applying *fact 2*, here $(S_t,A_t)$ is the $X$, and $G_t$ is the $Y$.)

Comment: This was great, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact 1, your proof is for a conditional expected value giving a particular value $Y=y$, but in PG formula the it's conditioned on RV $Y$. I am too struggling with this derivation on the book. RL course on YT based on the book usually skip this derivation which is kind of sad...

Answer (score 0):

The expectation of an expectation of a random variable (using the same assumptions, such as following the policy as here) is the same as the expectation of the random variable.

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]] = \mathbb{E}[X]$$

(provided $X$ and $Y$ are drawn from same probability space)

This rule appears with various names, but Wikipedia has it as [the law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: I'm familiar with the law of total expectation. It is not applicable here unfortunately.

Comment: @Miguel: Can you explain why it is not applicable here? $G_t$, $S_t$ and $A_t$ all seem to be drawn from same space, which is the only constraint.

Comment: Because the expression is of the form $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]\cdot Z]$ and not $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]]$

Comment: I think there is something more subtle going on here with the notation. In particular, the expectation in the first line is w.r.t $S_t$ and $A_t$, and the action value function is an expectation w.r.t $G_t$ conditional on $S_t$ and $A_t$. Putting this all together, the expectation in the third line should be w.r.t. $S_t$, $A_t$ and $G_t$. What is confusing is that the notation $\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[\cdot]$ is used for all of these different expectations.

Comment: @Miguel You can take the intermediate step you wrote and move what you're calling "Z" into the inner expectation, because your Z is a deterministic function of what you're calling "Y".  It's "taking out what is known" in reverse.  Guo Shuai's answer explains it in detail.